# Using a text file in an array. text file has 15 lines, name and 4 scores repeated 3 times. can't get the array to grab the text data

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file with 15 lines, a name with 4 test scores repeated for 3 total students. I am having trouble using the array to pull that data into the code.

Here is my work so far. **Main class** and the **Student Class**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;`enter code here`
public class StudentDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = keyboard.next();
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    System.out.println("The file " + fileName + 
                       "\ncontains the following lines:\n");

   try
   {
       inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
   }
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   {
       System.out.println("Error opening the file " + 
                           fileName);
       System.exit(0);
   }

   String []student = new String[15];
   int []scores = new int[15];
   for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
       scores[i] = 0;{
   String line = inputStream.nextLine();
   System.out.println(line);}

       while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
       {
           String line = inputStream.nextLine();
           System.out.println(line);
       }

       inputStream.close();

   StudentClass student1 = new StudentClass();
    student1.name = student[0];
    student1.q1 = scores[1];
    student1.q2 = scores[2];
    student1.e1 = scores[3];
    student1.e2 = scores[4];
    student1.writeOutput();

    StudentClass student2 = new StudentClass();
    student2.name = student[5];
    student2.q1 = scores[6];
    student2.q2 = scores[7];
    student2.e1 = scores[8];
    student2.e2 = scores[9];
    student2.writeOutput();

    StudentClass student3 = new StudentClass();
    student3.name = student[10];
    student3.q1 = scores[11];
    student3.q2 = scores[12];
            student3.e1 = scores[13];
            student3.e2 = scores[14];
    student3.writeOutput();

    keyboard.close();

  }

}


public class StudentClass {
    public String name;
    public int q1;
    public int q2;
    public int e1;
    public int e2;
//    double finalgrade;
    char finallettergrade;
    final double quizzesper = 0.25;
    final double exam1per = 0.25;
    final double exam2per = 0.50;

    public void writeOutput() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Quiz1: " + q1);
        System.out.println("Quiz2: " + q2);
        System.out.println("Exam1: " + e1);
        System.out.println("Exam2: " + e2);
        System.out.println("Final letter grade: " + finallettergrade);

     }

//    public void getFinalGrade()
//    {
       double finalgrade = ((q1 + q2)*5* quizzesper) + (e1 * exam1per)
                + (e2 * exam2per);
//    }
    public void finallettergrade(){
        if (finalgrade >= 90) {
            finallettergrade = 'A'; }
        else
            if (finalgrade >= 80 && finalgrade <= 89) {
                finallettergrade = 'B'; }
        else
                if (finalgrade >= 70 && finalgrade <= 79) {
                finallettergrade = 'C'; }
        else
                if (finalgrade >= 60 && finalgrade <= 69) {
                finallettergrade = 'D'; }
        else
                if (finalgrade >= 0 && finalgrade <= 59) {
                finallettergrade = 'F'; }

        }

    }
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: *i am having trouble* is not a question.

Comment: Take look at CSV https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html or https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Comment: first format proper code is unreadable

Comment: Can you share the file? If it has 15 lines, with student names and 4 scores would it translate to something like http://pastebin.com/raw/UZZq7FBB ? If so, why is the student array initialized with length 15?

Comment: Thank You, all the comments helped me understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Pavan, the text file is exactly like the link you have there. I realize now that it shouldn't be set to 15.

Answer (score 0):

example :

file to read in format:

```
name1,q1,q2,e1,e2
name2,q1,q2,e1,e2
name3,q1,q2,e1,e2
```

java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = keyboard.next();
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    System.out.println("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");

    // define a list interface to hold students - could be also primitive array   
    List<Student> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<>();
    //StudentCLass[] = listOfStudentsPrim = new StudentClass[expectedSize];

    try {
        // try read file 
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        // define user object to hold ref to new user while we will be iterating over file content 
        StudentClass student = null;
        // process lines 
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            // split line we assuming is delimited by ','
            String[] scoreLine = line.split(",");
            // prevent to make object while we have less then 5 parts
            if(scoreLine.length < 5) continue;

            // create student object 
            student = new StudentClass();
            // fill student
            student.name = scoreLine[0];
            student.q1 = scoreLine[1];
            student.q2 = scoreLine[2];
            student.e1 = scoreLine[3];
            student.e2 = scoreLine[4];
            student.writeOutput();

            // add student to list it may be also primitive  array - not interface  
            listOfStudents.add(student);
            // listOfStudentsPrim[index] = student;  // when we use prim array of objects 
        }   
        // catch exceptions 
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + fileName);
        System.exit(0);
        // finally try cleanup 
    } finally {
        // close if not null 
        if(inputStream!=null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    keyboard.close();
}
```